# Invalid initialization of non-const reference to type from a temporary of type

Tags: c++

My class structure is as follows:

Test_Camera.h:

```
class Test_Camera : public Camera_Interface {
public:
   Test_Camera (string const& aName);
   ...
```

Test_Camera.cpp

```
Test_Camera::Test_Camera(string const& aName) : Camera_Interface(0, 0, 0, 0), name(aName)
```

In my code that instantiates a `Test_Camera` object I have 2 scenarios. The first compiles fine, but the second doesn't and I can't figure out why.

```
Test_Camera cam ("cam"); // This compiles

Test_Camera& cam ("cam"); // This does not compile
```

When I try to compile the second example I get an error:

> error: invalid initialization of non-const reference to type 'Test_Camera&' from a temporary of type 'const char*'

I also tried:

```
string name = "cam";
Test_Camera& cam (name); //does not compile
```

Comment: You get the same error message for [ints](http://ideone.com/Dlpinm)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

References should refer to an existing object:

```
Test_Camera cam ("cam");
Test_Camera &cam_ref = cam;
```

Comment: Why is it that when I do `Test_Camera& cam ();` this compiles?

Comment: @Redek: Because that's a function prototype. The compiler assumes that `cam()` is function returning `Test_Camera&`.

Comment: @phresnel Thank you, that's where my confusion was.. I thought that it was calling the no-argument constructor. Makes a lot more sense now!